# Can one person hold "Project manager" and "Software Architect" at the same time?

Tags: architecture, project-management, roles

Is it possible for one person to take the two roles of "Project Manager" and "Software Architect" at the same time for the same project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TL;DR answer is: Yes they *can*; it is *possible*.

Whether they *should* is a different question.

I believe that the two roles should be independent as they need two very different views of the project, and may hold conflicting opinions as to approaches to follow.

Of course, you need to decide who has the casting vote...

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible for different reasons. However it is not desirable, since in a RACI (Roles, Accountability, Consulted, Informed) matrix this creates and maintains a potential conflict since there are different drivers and motivations for the respective roles. In my experience this did not work well, I had to recover projects run by Architects, since their focus and motivation were different than a project lifecycle.